# Media Library SSL

Tags: media-library

How can I tell the Wordpress Media Library to work on https protocol instead of http protocol?

None of the plugins I tried so far worked, and not even defining the FORCE_SSL_ADMIN constant as true.

Comment: what does it mean "work on https protoco"?

Comment: @MarkKaplun To load the images with https protocol. When I upload an image, at the sidebar it says "URL: http://...." and it makes the browser show a security alert.

Comment: if this is important enough for you just move the whole site to https. any hybrid http/https site will not always be easy to manage and will depend in all kind of ways on what kind of integrations you do with 3rd party services

Comment: @MarkKaplun Thanks for your time. It is important because the url is being saved as http in the database and hence creating mixed ssl alerts. I actually am using https everywhere it's just the media library creating the problems (which I know is already set as a ticket in the wordpress core fix list). Do you think using javascript to rewrite the url after uploading an image is a good solution?

Comment: you will either need to search replace your content and replace HTTPS with HTTP, or use a filter on `the_content` that will do it. The first option is probably what you should do if you have a fully https site.

Comment: @MarkKaplun In some cases the media library is used to set CSS image backgrounds for places that are not "the content". Should I search-replace the whole HTML of the website before outputting?. I do not see this as a clean approach. Do you know any way to just fix the media library and force it to set the media urls with https?